# MSDN open dialog box sample code

Tags: c++, windows

So I'm trying to run and compile this piece of sample code from MSDN (opening a dialig box):
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff485843(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff485843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

My compiler gives an error:
main.cpp: In function 'int wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int)':
main.cpp:19:9: error: 'IFileOpenDialog' was not declared in this scope

What I get from the documentation is that CoInitializeEx function should link against the necessary COM libraries and import the needed functions. Though I am totally new to C++ and Windows and for sure I'm getting something wrong.

I use Netbeans, MinGW and MSYS.

Can somebody help me out what is happening here and how to solve?

Comment: Did you include everything according to the example? Can you show your current code?

Comment: In MinGW, it´s possible that this stuff is missing. The Winapi is huge, not everything is ported.

Comment: I just copied and pasted everything that is there. Assuming it is missing how would you go about solving the issue?

Comment: Other than trying to use VS headers in MinGW, or using VS itself; or make the stuff for the MinGW project? Use the alternative of the answer below...

Answer (score 1):

MinGW g++ as of version 4.8.2 (the one I have) does not yet support Windows API functions or interfaces that were introduced in Windows Vista or later.

As a workaround you can use the old [`GetOpenFileName` or `GetSaveFileName` dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Alternatively download and install Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop, and use Visual C++.

Comment: Thanks, I would have spent ages figuring that. I'd like to learn to program in Windows, you seem to have some knowledge and reputation: How would you go about that? MSDN seems to rely hard on Visual Studio. Is there a better resource to learn windows that does not bound me to any dependency?

Comment: Or is it just simply that MinGW does simply not contain the stuff that is necessary?

Comment: Of course, MSDN and VS are made by the same company... and when using "unusual" things from the API, VS is still the easiest way to go. And yes, MinGW just lacks this stuff, because no one has made it until now.

Comment: @user3718333: I learned Windows programming from Petzold's classic "Programming Windows" book, then for Windows 3.1, or maybe it was 3.0 :). Using Visual C++. But the latest edition of that book is reportedly C# and .NET, not API level as I understand it. You might get up and running by using my old [Windows API tutorial](http://learnwinapi.wordpress.com/), where I made sure all examples could be built using MinGW g++.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think you spared me a bunch of white hair strings:)