# What compilers can i use for C++ when working with WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi, g++

(Very beginner knowledge of C++, WinAPI and compilers in general)

I much prefer using compilers over IDE's (not entirely sure why), and I have been using G++ (MinGW) up until now. Unfortunately I have started trying to do some code in WinAPI and was confused when Microsoft's tutorial code failed to compile (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows). I am now aware that G++ does not support WinAPI past the days of Windows Vista (fount this out here [MSDN open dialog box sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173443/msdn-open-dialog-box-sample-code)) this will be a problem for me, I love G++ but am not willing to cripple myself by using heavily outdated coding practices.

I am not entirely sure what a compiler without an IDE is called, and have not yet found a replacement for G++. I would be very grateful if you could give me suggestions for a C++ compiler that would support the latest WinAPI features. Cheers! (-:

For reference I use notepad++ and powershell

Comment: An IDE and a compiler are two completely different things. A compiler translates code and an IDE as a toolbox including a compiler (in most cases).

Comment: AFAIR, MinGW supports WinAPI by default. You should like it, since it is basically a port of GCC for Windows. I haven't use it for a long time but I think Mingw-w64 is the currently developed version?

Comment: This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549123/how-to-use-the-windows-api-in-mingw

Comment: Vast majority of professional Windows developers are using visual studio IDE. Microsoft only supports their Windows SDK for their VC++ compilers. If you’re an individual developer, or work in a company with less than 250 people, less than 250 computers, and less than $1 million annual revenue, the IDE is free (community edition).
Technically you can consume most of the WinAPI with any compiler, or use VC++ from command line without IDE, but you must be prepared to solve many unusual issues with that setup. If you’re only starting with C++, I wouldn’t recommend that path.

Comment: Visual Studio has "a C++ compiler that would support the latest WinAPI features", hopefully.

Comment: You should be using Visual Studio 2019 when following Microsoft tutorials.

Comment: @Soonts Yeah you're probably right, good to hear they have a command line version, that'll be fun! Would there be any legal thinks to take into account when using VS community?

Comment: @AshFire In a few words, you may use it for working on open source, or for anything at all if that’s not for work or your employer ain’t an enterprise. Complete terms there: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt031819/ I’m an individual developer, been using free IDEs since VS2017. If you’ll decide to use just the compiler, click “Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019” or “Developer PowerShell for VS 2019” shortcut in start menu.

Comment: @AshFire VC++ compiler is cl.exe, linker is link.exe. Or you can use projects/solutions, and msbuild.exe to compile + link your stuff from command-line.

Comment: _"I much prefer using compilers over IDE's"_, well you're mistaken. Using a good IDE really simplyfies a lot of things. Visual Studio is a pretty good IDE and the builtin debugger is powerful and straight forward to use

Comment: If you don't like IDEs, Microsoft other their [build tools](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-visual-studio-build-tools/) as a separate download.